# Is there a way a to reuse mongodb/mongose aggregation code?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb via mongoose. I have a number of mongodb aggregation queries that look almost alike so the aggregation code is like 90% similar. Can I reuse mongodb aggregaion code to avoid repetition? Or how can I design mu codebase to be DRY?

For example, consider the code below:

```
CreatedPost.aggregate([
        // $match can be dynamic
        {$sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
        {$lookup:{from:"users",localField:"creator",foreignField:"_id",as:"userWhoCreatedThisPost"}},
        // Plus other lookups like likes comments etc
        {$project:{
            userWhoCreatedThisPost:{
                _id:'$userWhoCreatedThisPost._id',
                name:'$userWhoCreatedThisPost.name',
            },  
            postText:'$postText',
            createdAt : '$createdAt',
            numberOfLikes:{$size:'$likes'},
            numberOfComments:{$size:'$comments'},
            // plus many more details
        }}

    ])
```

In the query above, you can reuse the code for different purposes by just changing (or adding) the `$match` parameter. For example if you want to get posts to display to a timeline or if you want posts only this user has created or if you want just one post.

Is it possible to reuse mongodb aggregation code? And if so, how do you do it? Or is there an alternative way to avoid repeating code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, that's a simple object, so you can keep the object somewhere and reuse it, or maybe create a function that you can parameterize on whatever you want, which would return the object.

You can even keep parts of it and re-assemble:

```
let sortByLatest = { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } };
let findCreator = { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "creator", foreignField: "_id", as: "userWhoCreatedThisPost" } };
// ...

CreatedPost.aggregate([ sortByLatest, findCreator, ... ]);
```

Or have functions that return parts:

```
let matchStatus = (status) => ({ $match: { status } });

CreatedPost.aggregate([ sortByLatest, findCreator, matchStatus("Done"), ... ]);
```

Or modify the parts as you apply them:

```
CreatedPost.aggregate([
    // pick a different collection, but keep the rest of the lookup
    { $lookup: { ...findCreator["$lookup"], from: "authors" } },
    ...
]);
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine two objects for example `sortByLatest` and `findCreator` into one object? or one array? I am trying to do that in my code but it is not working.

Comment: I just figured it out.(I am using javascript). I grouped the stages in arrays and used the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to 'open up the array'.

Comment: @YulePale, I think `$sort` and `$lookup` are different pipeline stages, so it's likely that you can't combine them into a single operation. You can just place them one after the other inside the pipeline array though. You can use the spread operator to create a new array from a previous array of stages, or even to create a new stage from a previous stage, as in the last example.